# Ошибка при подключении базы данных с помощью redbeanphp

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Здравствуйте, пишу регистрацию для сайта. Подключаю базу данных и пишет ошибка:

> PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/lib/rb.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/s/sashkai0/site/public_html/db.php on line 3

Я уже делаю сайт на хостинге (не локальном). user (это ведь логин для входа в хостинг?). Первый скриншот это код файла db.php для подключения базы данных, а второй это список баз данных. Как исправить ребята?[image: код базы данных]
[image: Базы данных]

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуюсь этим вопросом, чтобы обратить внимание всех новичков на два очень важных момента:

1. Начинающему программисту очень важно **внимательно читать сообщение об ошибке.** Даже с гугл переводчиком оно даст хотя бы примерное представление о проблеме. В частности о том, что оно не имеет никакого отношения к списку баз данных. А касается файла, который мы пытаемся подключить через require. То есть, прочитав сообщение об ошибке, ты уже не будешь метаться раненым сайгаком в разные стороны, а будешь заниматься конкретной причиной возникшей проблемы. В частности, очень помогает погуглить соощение об ошибке.
2. Начинающему программисту очень важно изучить хотя бы основы компьютерной грамотности. В данном случае - [различие между относительными и абсолютными путями](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths). В данном случае видно, что идет попытка подключить файл `/lib/rb.php` **из корня диска**, хотя, разумеется, такого файла там нет и быть не может. А файл лежит **в корне сайта**, то есть, обращаться к нему надо как

   ```
   require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/lib/rb.php';
   ```

Comment: а 'user', 'password' это данные чего нужно брать? у меня на хостинге сказано, что имя пользователя совпадает с именем БД, а пароль базы данной?

Answer (score 1):

Он тебе по английски говорит: не могу найти(открыть) файл /lib/rb.php вызванный на на строке 3, в файле /home/s/sashkai0/site/public_html/db.php.

Answer (score 1):

Создай `db.php`, в него подключи `rb.php` и потом уже везде подключай `db.php`, если этого не сделаешь потом могут быть проблемы.